# how to use a string as formula for mathematical calculations in php?

Tags: php, mysql

There are several mathematical formulas stored in mysql rows for individual usage. i.e. a field contains this formula as a string (varchar): **(($a+$b)/$c)**

Now in php variables are filled dynamically by an foreach loop:

```
$temp_array[$deviceData["devicename"]] = $deviceSum;
```

**$deviceData["devicename"] represents $a, $b, $c**.

The array can look like $a=>20, $b=>30, $c=>580.

**How can i use this variables with the string-formula?**

thx for helping.

Comment: can u share your sql query

Comment: You can use PHP's `eval` function for that something like `eval("<?php (($a+$b)/$c) ?>")` -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to eval it.

And if the values are like:

```
$deviceData["devicename"] = [
    'a' => 20,
    'b' => 30,
    'c' => 580
];
```

You might want to isolate them as you will need to `extract()` them out to make use if there is more then 3 etc, encapsulating in function/closure would work.

```
<?php
$formula = '(($a+$b)/$c)';

$deviceData["devicename"] = ['a' => 20, 'b' => 30, 'c' => 580];

$runFormula = function ($formula, $data) { 
    extract($data); 
    return eval('return '.$formula.';'); 
};

echo $runFormula($formula, $deviceData["devicename"]);
```

https://3v4l.org/I2rbk

Or just:

```
extract($deviceData["devicename"]); 
echo eval('return '.$formula.';');
```

But you're polluting your global variable table with whats extracted, potentially causing more issues.

**Though dont use eval if the *formula* is defined by the user, or your will have security issues.**

---

> In no respect shall I incur any liability for any damages, including,
>   but limited to, direct, indirect, special, or consequential damages
>   arising out of, resulting from, or any way connected to the use of the
>   code provided, whether or not based upon warranty, contract, tort, or
>   otherwise; whether or not injury was sustained by persons or property
>   or otherwise; and whether or not loss was sustained from, or arose out
>   of, the results of, the use if this code. ;p

Comment: Thx! i will test it right now! Formulas are defined only by the admin user with special security rights.

Comment: Then it should be ok, just be aware as it could end in tears and 2 week notices ;p

Comment: And also be aware that if the formula is not syntactically correct it will break your application as with any other syntax error.

Comment: Just when I thought I had seen everything, `return eval('return '.$formula.';');` is a new one for me so +1

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Inception ;p `return eval('return eval(\'return '.$formula.';\');'); `

Comment: This seems unethical, even for PHP lol. btw, my [spinning top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMpdi.jpg) hasn't stopped spinning since I came across your answer...

Comment: @Jaydp yep, your right, but that's a given, as division by zero will error anyway

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for reply but it stops page load when get this warning. So, need to do some modification for this. Anyway good solution.

Comment: Its also little difficult to check to add some validation in, as the formula would need parsing to see if its a division and then loop over the input to check for 0's, would prob need to build it out quite abit to handle things.