# How to find and replace text string at specific character (PHP)?

Tags: php, find

In `PHP`, I have string like this:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {consectetur} adipiscing elit. Sed cursus ante dapibus {diam}.";
```

and I want to find and `replace` words inside {} with `"BINGO"`.

Results:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, BINGO adipiscing elit. Sed cursus ante dapibus BINGO."
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want the same value for all between `{}`? why?

Comment: This is just example.

Comment: Is this for templating placeholders, or do you only want to change to one value? Anyways, my answer below covers both.

Comment: Actually i have equation inside {(123+2)/2}. I need calculate and print ansver.

Comment: lol, you left the biggest part out.. your need to regex that out, and eval it, then use the result as the value. You need to open a new question, you cant move the goal posts like that.

Comment: This will help if your confident that your values are equations and not php code, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49856199/how-to-use-a-string-as-formula-for-mathematical-calculations-in-php/49856574#49856574

Comment: All equations i'm making myself. That mean i'm confident. Thank You.

Comment: This should work then: https://3v4l.org/DOBAt

Comment: Perfect!!! Thumbs Up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$vars = [
    'consectetur' => 'BINGO',
    'diam' => 'BINGO'
];

$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {consectetur} adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus {diam}. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum.";

$parsed = preg_replace_callback("/\{([\w\_]{1,})\}/", function ($match) use ($vars) {
    return array_key_exists($match[1], $vars) ? $vars[$match[1]] : '';
}, $str);

echo $parsed;
```

https://3v4l.org/BbtbK

Or as you seem to want, which is kind of useless.

`echo preg_replace("/\{(.*?)\}/", 'BINGO', $str);`

https://3v4l.org/AHGXP

Comment: This is still the best answer so far. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace

```
<?php
$string = 'your String';
$pattern = '/\{(.*?)\}/';
$replacement = 'BINGO';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Comment: Sorry for last wrong version. I have corrected it. Try this

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match() with str_replace -

```
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {consectetur} adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus {diam}. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum.";

preg_match('{(.*)}', $str , $matches);

print_r($matches);

output - Array ( [0] => {hello:{}{}yooohooo} [1] => {hello:{}{}yooohooo} )
```

Use this output inside str_replace() function of php

```
echo str_replace($matches[0],"Your Replacing string",$str);
```

OR

You can use preg_replace() function

```
 $replace_str = preg_replace('{(.*)}', "Your Replacing string", $str);

   echo $replace_str;
```

I hope this will help you!